# how to connect the database file in sql server to exe file

Tags: sql-server

I am using an sql server and I'm just new in this field, every year my new company is renewing their database. How can I reconnect the application or the executable file to the new database file in sql server?? Can anybody help or does anyone have an idea?

Comment: it's due to DB address. if you have no change on port and IP, no need to change

Comment: Welcome to SO. however your question is too vague to generate any good answer. what you might want to do is, check the code of these applications, if you only have front end access to these applications, you might want to check within the application if it allows to connect to databases.

If you want to just connect SSMS or any other database developer tool to the SQL Server, that is a different thing. is that what you want to do ?

Comment: what do you mean by `every year my new company is renewing their database` ?

Comment: mahradbt,,im still new in this field..what i want to asked ,how can i connect or associate the exe file to our database file in sql server,

Comment: You can create a table which store database name or connection string values year wise and pickup connection string from that table based on the year.

Comment: @randeeLauresta You need to use `DB_NAME()` function to get the database name, all what you need is to get the `ID` of the database.